# ODBC, SQLSetEnvAttr gives 'Invalid handle'

Tags: c++, odbc

I am trying to connect to an SQL Server using ODBC (C++) on Windows.
Everything works on my developer machine, and on my build server (which both have Visual Studio 2022 installed).

But when I deploy the app to a user's machine I get 'Invalid handle' from this statement:

```
TRYODBC(hEnv,
        SQL_HANDLE_ENV,
        SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv,
            SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
            (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3,
            0));
```

The whole function looks like this:

```
int __cdecl ConnectOdbc(wchar_t* _connectionString)
{
    errorCodeOfsOdbc = (int)noErrorOfs;
    // Allocate an environment
    hEnv = 0;

    errorCodeOfsOdbc = unableToAllocateAnEnvironmentHandleOfs;

    if (SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv) == SQL_ERROR)
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"Unable to allocate an environment handle\n");
        return errorCodeOfsOdbc;
    }

    // Register this as an application that expects 3.x behavior,
    // you must register something if you use AllocHandle

    errorCodeOfsOdbc = (int)SQLSetEnvAttrErrorOfs;

    TRYODBC(hEnv,
        SQL_HANDLE_ENV,
        SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv,
            SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
            (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3,
            0));

    errorCodeOfsOdbc = (int)hDbcHandleErrorOfs;

    hDbc = 0;

    // Allocate a connection
    TRYODBC(hEnv,
        SQL_HANDLE_ENV,
        SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, &hDbc));

    if (hDbc == 0)
    {
        return errorCodeOfsOdbc;
    }

    // Connect to the driver.  Use the connection string if supplied
    // on the input, otherwise let the driver manager prompt for input.

    TRYODBC(hDbc,
        SQL_HANDLE_DBC,
        SQLDriverConnect(hDbc,
            NULL, //GetDesktopWindow(),
            _connectionString,
            SQL_NTS,
            NULL,
            0,
            NULL,
            SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE));

    fwprintf(stderr, L"Connected!\n");

    errorCodeOfsOdbc = (int)hStmtErrorOfs;

    hStmt = 0;

    TRYODBC(hDbc,
        SQL_HANDLE_DBC,
        SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hDbc, &hStmt));

    if (hStmt == 0)
    {
        return errorCodeOfsOdbc;
    }

    errorCodeOfsOdbc = (int)noErrorOfs;

    return errorCodeOfsOdbc;

Exit: // TODO

//    errorCodeOdbc = exitOdbcError;
    //return ExitOdbc();
    return errorCodeOfsOdbc;
}
```

If the environment handle is invalid, I would expect an error from the preceding statement:

```
if (SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv) == SQL_ERROR)
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"Unable to allocate an environment handle\n");
        return errorCodeOfsOdbc;
    }
```

But apparently there is no error...

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?